# "Missing Final End Statement" occurs in Fort77 but not GFortran

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I'm attempting to compile Fortran 77 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS using Fort77 and am getting a compilation error regarding the end statement that I am not receiving in GFortran. This seems to be proper Fortran 77 code, and I have tried all combinations of "end", "end program", "end program hello", and "stop".

Here is an example program:

```
    program hello
        implicit none
        write (*,*) "Hello, World!"
    end
```

While GFortran works perfectly, Fort77 gives me this compilation error:

```
$ fort77 -o hello hello.f
MAIN test:
Warning on line 3: missing final end statement
I/O error on c_file
/usr/bin/fort77: aborting compilation
```

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have an unprintable character at the end of a line?  Likewise, do you have a newline character at the end of the `end` line?  PS: what is fort77 and why would you want use that instead of gfortran?

Comment: Thanks, adding a newline at the end of the end line worked to get rid of the error, but then when it compiles it says "MAIN hello:" and the program can run but does not write Hello, World! I'll ditch this compiler. I'm trying to test some Fortran 77 code with another compiler besides Gfortran, because it's getting some undefined reference errors when using a C library when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Need a little more information about gfortran having undefined references when calling a C library function.  Error messages and compiler options are important.  My guess is you haven't read the gfortran doc about mix language programming.

Comment: Thank you, but I only need information about Fort77 for a comparison is all. I haven't had any trouble with undefined references outside of this specific case. I could post another question for that though if I need to.

Comment: Try to add an empty line after the `end`. Check that all rules about the fixed forms (column numbers) are followed.

Comment: Adding an empty line after the end was the answer. Good ideas! If anyone could expand on why newlines are required in some compilers and not others, or where it’s stated that could be helpful.

Comment: @evets: IIRC "fort77" is a script that runs f2c + gcc. IMHO not a sensible option for anything in 2019, but YMMV.

Comment: @janneb, thanks for the info.  I agree that the use of f2c+gcc is not sensible.

Comment: True, that makes sense. The C library stated it was compatible with G77Fortran and had issues with others, so I went looking for a few alternatives. It might be best to change the library’s Fortran wrapper. Exposed symbols begin with “C” in the wrapper when they should be lowercase and do not include a “C” in the examples.

Comment: Note that `implicit none` was introduced in Fortran 90. A strict FORTRAN 77 compiler would reject this.